# How to read a long multiline string line by line in python

Tags: python

I have a wallop of a string with many lines.  How do I read the lines one by one with a `for` clause?  Here is what I am trying to do and I get an error on the textData var referenced in the `for line in textData` line.

```
for line in textData
    print line
    lineResult = libLAPFF.parseLine(line)
```

The textData variable does exist, I print it before going down, but I think that the pre-compiler is kicking up the error.

Comment: You need to split your line into separate strings.  Having a "/n" in it doesn't make it a separate string.

Comment: What error are you getting (with the traceback)? What's the value in `textData`? Can you give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), something we can run and see the same problem as you so we can explain it to you?

Comment: Also, what is the "pre-compiler" that you think is "kicking up the error"?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

What about using [`.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)?

```
for line in textData.splitlines():
    print(line)
    lineResult = libLAPFF.parseLine(line)
```

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: `"/r"` and `"/n"` are just normal two-character strings consisting of a slash and a letter. Did you mean `"\n"`?

Comment: Is it a copy or an iterator?

Comment: @user3226167 it returns a _list_.

Comment: Is there an iterator version of splitlines that would not create list, but instead return in iterator?

Comment: There is StringIO, but it is a lower level interface. That said in this case you already have a string - if you want to iterate an iterator (a file for example) line by line that's another question. Remember - in this case you already have a string.

Comment: Yea, but constructing an array of them seems kinda wasteful when you just want to read one line at a time. Imagine it's some really big string, then constructing an array of lines more than duplicates the memory used.

Comment: Memory concerns and having a large string seem like two mutually exclusive patterns. However - I totally get there are some cases where one would want this - for that there is StringIO.

Comment: It's not a memory concern but a performance concern. Copying the whole string into a list of strings is stupid when you work line-by-line.

Answer (score 6):

by splitting with newlines.

```
for line in wallop_of_a_string_with_many_lines.split('\n'):
  #do_something..
```

if you iterate over a string, you are iterating char by char in that string, not by line.

```
>>>string = 'abc'
>>>for line in string:
    print line

a
b
c
```

Comment: For anyone reading this now, use str.splitlines() function instead. Some edge cases arise with this solution. For ex. say you iterate over each line, if there is a \n at the end of the final line of the object then your for loop will try and perform a task on an empty line causing errors. Discussed above in accepted solution.

Answer (score 4):

This answer fails in a couple of edge cases (see comments). The accepted solution above will handle these. `str.splitlines()` is the way to go. I will leave this answer nevertheless as reference.

Old (incorrect) answer:

```
s =  \
"""line1
line2
line3
"""

lines = s.split('\n')
print(lines)
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Comment: `split('\n')` will retain any `\r` characters within the sting. Carriage returns won't get deleted, which could be a problem.

Comment: very good point. I think this answer is not correct because there are a couple of edge cases that `splitlines()` will catch, but my solution does not. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines