# Stop the command when find a string - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I want to print a command until it finds the main.py file and then stops.

I tried this code but according to logic it is printing the code several times and not line by line until I stop at mine where I find the main.py file.

```
import subprocess

#store ls -l to variable
get_ls = subprocess.getoutput("ls -l")

#transfom output to string
ls = str(get_ls)

#search for main.py file in ls
for line in ls:
  main_py = line.find('main.py')
  print(ls)

  #if find main.py print stop and exit
  if main_py == 'main.py':  
    print('stop...')
    exit()
```

Output is looping this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner 9009 Feb 19 19:00 poetry.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner  354 Feb 19 19:00 pyproject.toml
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner  329 Feb 25 00:10 main.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner  383 Feb 14 17:57 replit.nix
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner   61 Feb 19 18:46 urls.tmp
drwxr-xr-x 1 runner runner   56 Oct 26 20:53 venv
```

I want this output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner 9009 Feb 19 19:00 poetry.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner  354 Feb 19 19:00 pyproject.toml
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner  329 Feb 25 00:10 main.py
###### stops here #######
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a long multiline string line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422144/how-to-read-a-long-multiline-string-line-by-line-in-python)

Comment: You're currently iterating over a string character by character. Also, `ls = str(get_ls)` is useless, as getoutput already returns a string. `print(ls)` should also be `print(line)`.

Comment: @SuperStormer yeah, now i see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `for line in ls` isn't doing what you think it is. Instead of going line by line, it's going through `ls` character by character. What you want to have is `for line in ls.splitlines()`. You can then check if `main.py` is on that line by calling `"main.py" in line`

```py
import subprocess

#store ls -l to variable
get_ls = subprocess.getoutput("ls -l")

#transfom output to string
ls = str(get_ls)

#search for main.py file in ls
for line in ls.splitlines():
  print(line)

  #if find main.py print stop and exit
  if "main.py" in line:  
    print('stop...')
    exit()
```

That should be more what you want I think.

You're also printing `ls` every loop, which you need to change to only print the current line

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you only want to achieve the result and don’t mind changing your logic, this the most elegant, and which is the most "pythonic" one. I like the simplicity of the os.walk() method:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        
        if filename == "main.py":
            print("stop")
            break
```